# django - how to use current user that loged in model (in the way that he cant choose another user)

Tags: django, authentication, django-models

i want to make a blog with django that any user can create posts and post owned by just that user .the author of the post most be the current user that loged in and never change. i have a problem to get current user in post model !!

how i store current that wrote the post with post model ?

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField

class Post(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = {
    
    }
    TECHNOLOGY_CHOICES = {
    
    }

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250,unique_for_date='publish')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    body = RichTextField(config_name='default',blank=True, null=True)

    publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='draft')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=250,default='other')

    def __str__(self):

        return self.title + ' |  ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')
```

Comment: Share your view where you create `Post` objects.

Comment: i think a solution to this issue would be to make a Modelform for the Post and in the Init of the model form make the author field hidden...and then manually add the request.user object to the form in a view as an initial value.....i have done something similiar, sharing your view code for the form could help

Answer (score 0):

also we have django mixins to do something like this for us
django mixins is for authentication system , if we use the view class in views.py file like below, the django shows any user 404 page for edit page and delete page except the post creator user :

if we import  :

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import (
    LoginRequiredMixins,
    UserPassesTestMixin
)
```

and use them in View class :

```
class PostUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostUpdateForm
    template_name = 'weblog/post/post_update.html'

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user



class DeletePostView(LoginRequiredMixin,UserPassesTestMixin,UpdateView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'weblog/post/post_delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def test_func(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        return obj.author == self.request.user
```

with this code we didnt need to even change the html to check user.

post page html :

```
<div class="form-group">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary"> Update Now</button>
            </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if we make view for post creation and use CreateView for customizing it like below the current user pushed to database :

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreateForm
    template_name = 'weblog/post/post_create.html'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

just remember if you use post creation form or in views fields dont use author user in fields. this code sent current user to database.
and for editing the post u can check if the current user is the post maker then show edit page html :

```
{% if user.id == post.author.id %}
        <div class="form-group">
            <form method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button class="btn btn-primary"> Update Now</button>
            </form>
        </div>
 {% else %}
        <h2>there is no such page for you ! </h2>
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

and the PostCreateForm and PostUpdateForm in forms.py is :

```
class PostCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','slug','body','status')
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': RichTextField(config_name='default'),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            
    }


class PostUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title','slug','body','status',)
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': RichTextField(config_name='default'),
            'status': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),

    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).